# Tagging elements in header and footer in ConTeXt

Tags: context, accessibility

When generating a tagged PDF with ConTeXt, the content that I have in my header and footer isn't tagged.

This makes sense since they are not actually part of the page flow. However, it also causes the document to fail Acrobat's accessibility tagging test for all elements.

Is there a way to tag them as "Artifacts" so that they are ignored by these checks?

I've tried to wrap the footer elements in element tags which didn't work.

```
\setupfootertexts[][\startelement[Artifact] {Footer Text} \stopelement]
```

Comment: I know that tagging is done under the hood using `\dostarttagged{<tag>}{<detail>} ... \dostoptagged` but I'm unsure how to apply this here.  Maybe it is better to ask on the mailing list.

Comment: Are there any news here?